# How do I pull singe cell RNA sequencing data from GEO database?

Tags: r, scrnaseq, phylogenetics, geoquery

I am new to R and computational biology. I am trying to look through a published data set to check for gene expression for my own project. I am having trouble finding materials to teach me how to analyze single cell RNA sequencing data on R from the GEO NCBI database.

This is the data that I am trying to access https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE138651

I would appreciate any directions or suggestions for tutorials.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Install package

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
```

Use function getGEO to download the files.

```
expressionSet <- getGEO("GSE138651")
expressionSet <- expressionSet[[1]]
```

You can then look at the info of the samples:

```
pData(expressionSet)
```

And the assay data itself

```
exprs(expressionSet)
```

Comment: This is useful because of the very specific instructions but I think it would be even more helpful to also include a brief introductory explanation and links to BioConductor and the GEOquery package to provide context for newcomers.

Comment: I am sorry but I have to flag this for removal since it's wrong. getGEO only returns expression data for arrays, not for NGS. Output of `exprs(expressionSet)` is empty and this is expected.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest would be using a count matrix (at the end of the link you have shared, section "Supplementary file"). For example `GSE138651_Vagal_WholeNodoseSeq_raw.mtx.gz` corresponds to "raw" count matrices obtained after mapping and counting the reads. This file, along with the `GSE138651_barcodes.tsv.gz` and `GSE138651_genes.tsv.gz` can be used to "read" the data into `R`; to that end there are many options in the form of packages, [Seurat](https://satijalab.org/seurat/) is one of the best documented and hence is beginner-friendly.

Comment: Thanks Haci. I am learning Seurat as well. So many things!! 
I am actually the most interested in the file GSE138651_NGTall_Reads_cap.csv.gz. Do you know if this file type can be "read" into R?

Comment: Yes, it is a `csv` file and once again there are many options to read such files into `R`. `read.csv()` is one option. Personally, I use `fread()` of `data.table` to read in tabular files.

Comment: I will try that then. Thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check out the [BioConductor *`GEOquery`* package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GEOquery.html).

Install using

```r
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("GEOquery")
```

More information on how to use this package and read in data from GEO can be found in the [vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/GEOquery/inst/doc/GEOquery.html)

Comment: I am sorry but I have to flag this for removal since it's wrong. getGEO only returns expression data for arrays, not for NGS. This package does not apply here.